# I want to know how to send an email to list of people

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to send an alert to several hundereds of recipienats. I have the names in excel sheet, but some of these fields might be invalid entry. is there anyway I can make sharepoint accepts the valid entries and auto-delete the invalid ones, and proceed to send emails.
thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the emails are from SharePoint users, you can just do a cycle and check if users with such emails exist. When you have all valid emails, just append them to one string which will be added to email's "To" section. Hope it helps

Comment: how can I do such a cycle?

 and thank you so much in advance

Comment: Through for or foreach iterator, depends on which is more comfortable with you, personally i would do that with foreach